Junit5 Mockito testcases are not running in Eclipse
I am trying to run Junit5 testcases with Mockito. And I have added mockito-junit-jupiter:5.7.0 maven dependency in the project
When I do "maven clean install" at that time build is successful, but When I try to run the specific test case from Eclipse, it is giving me below error.
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface com.welldyne.wellserv.app.logic.services.CheckoutAppLogicService.


If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please open an issue on GitHub.



Java               : 11
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 11.0.22+9-LTS-219
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 11.0.22+9-LTS-219
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows Server 2016
OS version         : 10.0



You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:190)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:154)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:75)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:221)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.lambda$mockClass$0(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:78)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:75)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:412)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.doCreateMock(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:371)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:350)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:88)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:2101)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:28)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:44)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:72)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:47)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:81)
    at org.mockito.internal.framework.DefaultMockitoSession.<init>(DefaultMockitoSession.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.session.DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.startMocking(DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.java:83)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader$Builder.appendMostSpecific([Ljava/lang/Class;)Lnet/bytebuddy/dynamic/loading/MultipleParentClassLoader$Builder;
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:129)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.lambda$mockClass$0(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:78)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    ... 31 more
has context menu

Junit test class is as follow
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CheckoutControllerTest {
 
    @InjectMocks
    private CheckoutController checkoutController;
 
    @Mock
    private CheckoutService service;

 
    @Test
    void test_happy_scenario() {
        String uniqueMemberId = "memberId123";
    
        Order order = new Order();
        Mockito.when(service.getCurrentOrder(uniqueMemberId)).thenReturn(order);
 
        ...
 
    }
 

Please find attached pom.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.poroject.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>test-app</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <spring.boot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.boot.mobile.version>1.5.22.RELEASE</spring.boot.mobile.version>
        <junit.version>4.13</junit.version>
        <aws.sdk.version>1.11.762</aws.sdk.version>
        <elasticsearch.version>7.6.2</elasticsearch.version>
        <spring.swagger.version>2.9.2</spring.swagger.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.14.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xlint</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
                <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
                <version>6.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>vc.inreach.aws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-signing-request-interceptor</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.22</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
                <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-iam</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
                <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mobile</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.mobile.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.swagger.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.swagger.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity</artifactId>
                <version>${aws.sdk.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <version>1.65</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.brendamour</groupId>
                <artifactId>jpasskit</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>29.0-jre</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <!--<dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.10.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
                <!--<scope>test</scope> -->
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
</project>
 
 

I tried to check Eclipse configurations and it is pointing to the same java version, There is no duplicate library as well for net.bytebuddy.

I have been using below eclipse version.

Could you please help me to resolve the issue ?
Maven build from eclipse is successful, it is executing test cases without any error.
Normal Junit5 test cases (Without Mocking any class) are running via eclipse.
